# Manually deployed WinRT app behaves different compared to deployment from VS2013

Tags: web-services, rest, visual-studio-2013, win-universal-app

I've developed a universal app for Windows 8.1 and am now trying to install the built .appx package via powershell having no problem after installing the certificate. Though when I run the installed app it behaves differently as if I deploy/install the app from within Visual Studio.

The app is using (local) REST services to obtain data from different sources. While working when starting the app from Visual Studio, it is not when I create an .appx package and install it manually via powershell. Any hints where the problem is located?

Comment: If you're using a web service local to the device, the website must be running locally on the device with a predefined port in order for the app to use it.  Ideally, any deployment would utilize a website on a local domain - not the local device.  That is, if I'm understanding your problem correctly.

Comment: Well the configuration and the use of the web service isn't the cause of the problems. In detail, when I compile, deploy and run (F5) the app via Visual Studio it works perfectly fine. It calls the REST services, gets data from them and handles them well. Though when I create an app-package from Visual Studio and install the app via powershell (Add-appxpackage ...) the app runs, but when calling the REST services it gets no data and after a while a timeout occurs. As far as I've investigated the issue, it seems to have something to do with the certificate..?!